# What to do with tag wikis that verge on advertisements?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openshift. To me, this reads like someone's marketing dept wrote it. Does it bother anyone else? If so, what's the appropriate response?

Comment: I'd get rid of the advertisement part. Of course, if its a *sponsored* tag,  I don't believe there is much we can do

Comment: Looking at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10093250/5), the author of the edit that added the advertisement is a Red Hat employee.

Comment: I swapped the excerpt and the body.  Other than that, I don't see a problem, other than it's unusually cheerful.  Sheesh, those marketing types; don't they know anything?

Comment: @Louis: What really bothers me is that the edit description "Updating to make it shorter and more to the point" is an outright lie.  An edit that doubles the length of a wiki excerpt does not "make it shorter".  Full stop.

Comment: IMO the "[...] so that you can focus on writing code for your business, startup, or next big idea" part is noise and should be edited out. That has nothing to do with explaining what the tag is about and could in fact be added to most other tag wikis, e.g. "Python is a general-purpose, high-level programming language that is designed to emphasize usability, so that you can focus on [etc]". It does not add any value to the description.

Comment: @BenVoigt IMO the three users who approved the edit should have a review ban: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5858495, they obviously never read the edit summary as its an outright lie.

Comment: @cybermonkey: Nah, the edit summary is not what they are reviewing, the edit is.  Reviewers are supposed to look at the summary if they consider the edit questionable, since knowing the post author agreed with the edit in the comments can make all the difference... but if they can review without the summary, that's just more focus on what really matters.

Comment: @BenVoigt The excerpt was lengthened, but the wiki proper was [significantly shortened.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5858494) From the timing, my bet is that both edits were done at the same time with the summary referring to the wiki not the excerpt.

Comment: @numaroth Is correct. The system lets you edit both the wiki excerpt and body in a single action (with a single message), but shows the excerpt and body changes to reviewers separately (with the same message). This is a matter of confusing system design, not misconduct by the editor or reviewers.

Comment: @BenVoigt It [looks to me](https://i.imgur.com/RmyaCue.png) like the "shorter and more to the point" edit actually did shorten it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @WChargin: Yes, we're looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10093250/revisions).  numaroth already pointed out that the edit summary shows without the entire edit, so the "outright lie" is the fault of the system.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah! You're right. Sorry, missed that comment.

Comment: The tag wiki's for XPath and XSLT have also recently been updated to include references to training courses that are paid for, added by the author of those courses. This strikes me as inappropriate, but I'm not sure what the official position on cases like this is. Again, the XPath one includes a reference to the same user's tool, that reads like marketing info.

Comment: @Flynn1179 flag, please.

Comment: How? There's no 'flag' button/link on tag wikis.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at that tag wiki, the appropriate response is to edit (out) the offending parts, leaving it more neutral.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with this example. Although it sounds like an excerpt from their website, it is fairly short and descriptive.

If it were full of "Buy Now!" links or other commercial content, just edit it out.